# IF statement using a List<Bitmap>

Tags: if-statement, bitmap, picturebox

So I have looked through a few previous solutions but thus far have not seen any to fix my issue. I am trying to change a player's avatar when they click the picturebox. I have a list of images like so :

```
List<Bitmap> avatars = new List<Bitmap>();

private void GameForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  avatars.Add(Properties.Resources.Head1);
  avatars.Add(Properties.Resources.Head2);
  avatars.Add(Properties.Resources.Head3);
  avatars.Add(Properties.Resources.Head4);
}
```

And this is where I am trying to change it at :

```
private void pictureBoxAvatar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if(pictureBoxAvatar1.Image == avatars.ElementAt(0))
  {
    pictureBoxAvatar1.Image = avatars.ElementAt(1);
  }
  //I have four total possibilities, but just have this one statement until I figure it out

}
```

My issue is that I cannot find a condition to evaluate to switch the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with your approach which if changed might make things easier. First is that for each avatar you store a copy of the Image when you only need to store one copy per image. While this is fine in small programs it will not scale well. While the compiler **might** be smart enough to store each of the images only once, you run a big chance of creating a lot of redundant data and we shouldn't trust the compiler to handle this for us. Of course this might change our render approach a little but it should improve caching and allow the program to run a little faster.

The better solution would be to store the Images in one central location and for the avatars store a single pointer indicating which Images to use.

I would change `pictureBoxAvatar1.Image` to something along the lines of `pictureBoxAvatar1.ImagePointer` and then your function should become something like

```
private void pictureBoxAvatar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pictureBoxAvatar1.ImagePointer = (pictureBoxAvatar1.ImagePointer + 1) % avatars.size(); 
}
```

Comment: That approach worked! Thanks for the advice and critique, I'm always looking for ways to get better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
int avIndex = avatars.IndexOf(picturebox1.image);
avIndex++;
if (avIndex >= avatars.Count)
{ 
  avIndex = 0;
}
picturebox1.image = avatars[avIndex];
```

or equivalent depending on what avatars is.